# how to set up config file to access mysql database parameter

Tags: python-2.7, cherrypy

hi im new to python cherrypy framework.

how to set up config file to use mysql database object.

myapp.conf contain

[global]

server.socket_host = "127.0.0.1"

server.socket_port = 8080

server.thread_pool = 10

server.thread_pool = 10

[Databases]

driver: "mysql"

host: "localhost"

username: "testusers"

password: "bharti"

dbtable: "employe"

[/path]

response.timeout: 6000

i want to use myapp conf file to set database parameter in my application code.
how to access or use conf file...please help me out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this...

server.conf:

```
[Database]
host: '192.168.0.1'
user: 'user'
passwd: 'passwd'
port: 3306
db: 'data'
```

and access the settings this way in your python file:

```
from MySQLdb.cursors import DictCursor
MySQLconnection = MySQLdb.connect(host=cherrypy.request.app.config['Database']['host'], 
                                  passwd=cherrypy.request.app.config['Database']['passwd'],
                                  db=cherrypy.request.app.config['Database']['db'],
                                  user=cherrypy.request.app.config['Database']['user'],
                                  port=cherrypy.request.app.config['Database']['port'], 
                                  cursorclass=DictCursor)
MySQLcursor = MySQLconnection.cursor()
```

Hope this helps!

Andrew

Comment: what is dictcurosor?? cursorclass=dictcursor

Comment: I've updated my code with the proper import.  DictCursor allows you to access elements retrieved from the database using the column name. For instance DatabaseResults[0]['ColumnName'].  Here's more info http://www.gadzmo.com/python/using-pythons-dictcursor-in-mysql-to-return-a-dict-with-keys/